# PostgreSQL 9.5 showing unexpected behavior when installed with different locale other than default

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgresql-9.5, enterprisedb

On Windows 7, I am trying to install PostgreSQL 9.5 ( `postgresql-9.5.2-1-windows-x64.exe`) with different locales, but it is getting installed with default locale only, which is, `English_United States.1252`. I tried both the methods, GUI and unattended/silent, but the result is same.

I followed the below steps:

1. Set the locale of system to the particular locale, for ex. `English, Australia`.
2. Restarted the system.
3. Installed PostgreSQL using following command with parameter `--locale`:

   ```
   start /w postgresql-9.5.2-1-windows-x64.exe --mode unattended --unattendedmodeui none --superaccount "postgres" --superpassword "postgrespwd" --prefix "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5" --datadir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" --serverport "5432" --install_runtimes 1 --locale "English, Australia"
   ```
4. Executed the command:  `Show lc_collate` and got the output as `English_United States.1252`

Similarly, I followed the same steps while installing through GUI mode, selected option `English, Australia`.

Here is the output of PostgreSQL log file `bitrock_installer.log` (GUI mode):

```
Log started 11/08/2017 at 17:02:06
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Executing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_ec63d13cf6/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 "test ok"

Script stderr:


Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Data Directory. Setting variable iDataDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Service ID. Setting variable iServiceName to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Service Account. Setting variable iServiceAccount to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Super User. Setting variable iSuperuser to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 DisableStackBuilder. Setting variable iDisableStackBuilder to empty value
[17:02:13] Existing base directory: 
[17:02:13] Existing data directory: 
[17:02:13] Using branding: PostgreSQL 9.5
[17:02:13] Using Super User: postgres and Service Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
[17:02:13] Using Service Name: postgresql-x64-9.5
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_ec63d13cf6\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:


Executing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_ec63d13cf6\vcredist_x64.exe /passive /norestart
Script exit code: 0

Script output:


Script stderr:


Executing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_ec63d13cf6\getlocales.exe 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 AfrikaansxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Afrikaans, South Africa
AlbanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAlbania=Albanian, Albania
AlsatianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Alsatian, France
AmharicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEthiopia=Amharic, Ethiopia
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAlgeria=Arabic, Algeria
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBahrain=Arabic, Bahrain
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEgypt=Arabic, Egypt
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIraq=Arabic, Iraq
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxJordan=Arabic, Jordan
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKuwait=Arabic, Kuwait
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLebanon=Arabic, Lebanon
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLibya=Arabic, Libya
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMorocco=Arabic, Morocco
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxOman=Arabic, Oman
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxQatar=Arabic, Qatar
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSaudixxSPxxArabia=Arabic, Saudi Arabia
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSyria=Arabic, Syria
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTunisia=Arabic, Tunisia
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUxxDOTxxAxxDOTxxExxDOTxx=Arabic, U.A.E.
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxYemen=Arabic, Yemen
ArmenianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxArmenia=Armenian, Armenia
AssamesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Assamese, India
AzerixxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAzerbaijan=Azeri (Cyrillic), Azerbaijan
AzerixxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAzerbaijan=Azeri (Latin), Azerbaijan
BashkirxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Bashkir, Russia
BasquexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Basque, Spain
BelarusianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelarus=Belarusian, Belarus
BengalixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBangladesh=Bengali, Bangladesh
BengalixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Bengali, India
BosnianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Bosnian (Cyrillic), Bosnia and Herzegovina
BosnianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Bosnian (Latin), Bosnia and Herzegovina
BretonxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Breton, France
BulgarianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBulgaria=Bulgarian, Bulgaria
CatalanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Catalan, Spain
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxSimplifiedxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSingapore=Chinese (Simplified), Singapore
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHongxxSPxxKongxxSPxxSxxDOTxxAxxDOTxxRxxDOTxx=Chinese (Traditional), Hong Kong S.A.R.
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMacaoxxSPxxSxxDOTxxAxxDOTxxRxxDOTxx=Chinese (Traditional), Macao S.A.R.
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTaiwan=Chinese (Traditional), Taiwan
CorsicanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Corsican, France
CroatianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCroatia=Croatian, Croatia
CroatianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Croatian (Latin), Bosnia and Herzegovina
CzechxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCzechxxSPxxRepublic=Czech, Czech Republic
DanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxDenmark=Danish, Denmark
DarixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAfghanistan=Dari, Afghanistan
DivehixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMaldives=Divehi, Maldives
DutchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelgium=Dutch, Belgium
DutchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNetherlands=Dutch, Netherlands
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAustralia=English, Australia
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelize=English, Belize
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=English, Canada
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCaribbean=English, Caribbean
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=English, India
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIreland=English, Ireland
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxJamaica=English, Jamaica
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMalaysia=English, Malaysia
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNewxxSPxxZealand=English, New Zealand
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRepublicxxSPxxofxxSPxxthexxSPxxPhilippines=English, Republic of the Philippines
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSingapore=English, Singapore
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=English, South Africa
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTrinidadxxSPxxandxxSPxxTobago=English, Trinidad and Tobago
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxKingdom=English, United Kingdom
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxStates=English, United States
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxZimbabwe=English, Zimbabwe
EstonianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEstonia=Estonian, Estonia
FaroesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFaroexxSPxxIslands=Faroese, Faroe Islands
FilipinoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPhilippines=Filipino, Philippines
FinnishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Finnish, Finland
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelgium=French, Belgium
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=French, Canada
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=French, France
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLuxembourg=French, Luxembourg
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPrincipalityxxSPxxofxxSPxxMonaco=French, Principality of Monaco
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=French, Switzerland
FrisianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNetherlands=Frisian, Netherlands
GalicianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Galician, Spain
GeorgianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGeorgia=Georgian, Georgia
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAustria=German, Austria
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGermany=German, Germany
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLiechtenstein=German, Liechtenstein
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLuxembourg=German, Luxembourg
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=German, Switzerland
GreekxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGreece=Greek, Greece
GreenlandicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGreenland=Greenlandic, Greenland
GujaratixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Gujarati, India
HausaxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNigeria=Hausa (Latin), Nigeria
HebrewxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIsrael=Hebrew, Israel
HindixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Hindi, India
HungarianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHungary=Hungarian, Hungary
IcelandicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIceland=Icelandic, Iceland
IgboxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNigeria=Igbo, Nigeria
IndonesianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndonesia=Indonesian, Indonesia
InuktitutxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=Inuktitut (Latin), Canada
InuktitutxxSPxxxxOBxxSyllabicsxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=Inuktitut (Syllabics), Canada
IrishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIreland=Irish, Ireland
ItalianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxItaly=Italian, Italy
ItalianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=Italian, Switzerland
JapanesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxJapan=Japanese, Japan
KannadaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Kannada, India
KazakhxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKazakhstan=Kazakh, Kazakhstan
KhmerxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCambodia=Khmer, Cambodia
KinyarwandaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRwanda=Kinyarwanda, Rwanda
KiswahilixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKenya=Kiswahili, Kenya
KonkanixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Konkani, India
KoreanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKorea=Korean, Korea
KyrgyzxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKyrgyzstan=Kyrgyz, Kyrgyzstan
LaoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLaoxxSPxxPxxDOTxxDxxDOTxxRxxDOTxx=Lao, Lao P.D.R.
LatvianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLatvia=Latvian, Latvia
LithuanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLithuania=Lithuanian, Lithuania
LowerxxSPxxSorbianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGermany=Lower Sorbian, Germany
LuxembourgishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLuxembourg=Luxembourgish, Luxembourg
MacedonianxxSPxxxxOBxxFYROMxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMacedoniaxxSPxxxxOBxxFYROMxxCBxx=Macedonian (FYROM), Macedonia (FYROM)
MalayalamxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Malayalam, India
MalayxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBruneixxSPxxDarussalam=Malay, Brunei Darussalam
MalayxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMalaysia=Malay, Malaysia
MaltesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMalta=Maltese, Malta
MaorixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNewxxSPxxZealand=Maori, New Zealand
MapudungunxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChile=Mapudungun, Chile
MarathixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Marathi, India
MohawkxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=Mohawk, Canada
MongolianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMongolia=Mongolian (Cyrillic), Mongolia
NepalixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNepal=Nepali, Nepal
NorwegianxxSPxxxxOBxxBokmålxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Norwegian (Bokmål), Norway
NorwegianxxSPxxxxOBxxNynorskxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Norwegian (Nynorsk), Norway
OccitanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Occitan, France
OriyaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Oriya, India
PashtoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAfghanistan=Pashto, Afghanistan
PersianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIran=Persian, Iran
PolishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPoland=Polish, Poland
PortuguesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBrazil=Portuguese, Brazil
PortuguesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPortugal=Portuguese, Portugal
PunjabixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Punjabi, India
QuechuaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBolivia=Quechua, Bolivia
QuechuaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEcuador=Quechua, Ecuador
QuechuaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPeru=Quechua, Peru
RomanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRomania=Romanian, Romania
RomanshxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=Romansh, Switzerland
RussianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Russian, Russia
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxInarixxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Sami (Inari), Finland
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxLulexxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Sami (Lule), Norway
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxLulexxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Sami (Lule), Sweden
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxNorthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Sami (Northern), Finland
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxNorthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Sami (Northern), Norway
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxNorthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Sami (Northern), Sweden
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxSkoltxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Sami (Skolt), Finland
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxSouthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Sami (Southern), Norway
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxSouthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Sami (Southern), Sweden
SanskritxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Sanskrit, India
ScottishxxSPxxGaelicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxKingdom=Scottish Gaelic, United Kingdom
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Serbian (Cyrillic), Bosnia and Herzegovina
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMontenegro=Serbian (Cyrillic), Montenegro
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbia=Serbian (Cyrillic), Serbia
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbiaxxSPxxandxxSPxxMontenegroxxSPxxxxOBxxFormerxxCBxx=Serbian (Cyrillic), Serbia and Montenegro (Former)
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Serbian (Latin), Bosnia and Herzegovina
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMontenegro=Serbian (Latin), Montenegro
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbia=Serbian (Latin), Serbia
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbiaxxSPxxandxxSPxxMontenegroxxSPxxxxOBxxFormerxxCBxx=Serbian (Latin), Serbia and Montenegro (Former)
SesothoxxSPxxsaxxSPxxLeboaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Sesotho sa Leboa, South Africa
SetswanaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Setswana, South Africa
SinhalaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSrixxSPxxLanka=Sinhala, Sri Lanka
SlovakxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSlovakia=Slovak, Slovakia
SlovenianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSlovenia=Slovenian, Slovenia
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxArgentina=Spanish, Argentina
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBolivarianxxSPxxRepublicxxSPxxofxxSPxxVenezuela=Spanish, Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBolivia=Spanish, Bolivia
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChile=Spanish, Chile
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxColombia=Spanish, Colombia
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCostaxxSPxxRica=Spanish, Costa Rica
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxDominicanxxSPxxRepublic=Spanish, Dominican Republic
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEcuador=Spanish, Ecuador
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxElxxSPxxSalvador=Spanish, El Salvador
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGuatemala=Spanish, Guatemala
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHonduras=Spanish, Honduras
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMexico=Spanish, Mexico
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNicaragua=Spanish, Nicaragua
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPanama=Spanish, Panama
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxParaguay=Spanish, Paraguay
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPeru=Spanish, Peru
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPuertoxxSPxxRico=Spanish, Puerto Rico
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Spanish, Spain
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Spanish, Spain
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxStates=Spanish, United States
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUruguay=Spanish, Uruguay
SwedishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Swedish, Finland
SwedishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Swedish, Sweden
SyriacxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSyria=Syriac, Syria
TajikxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTajikistan=Tajik (Cyrillic), Tajikistan
TamazightxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAlgeria=Tamazight (Latin), Algeria
TamilxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Tamil, India
TatarxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Tatar, Russia
TeluguxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Telugu, India
ThaixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxThailand=Thai, Thailand
TurkishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTurkey=Turkish, Turkey
TurkmenxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTurkmenistan=Turkmen, Turkmenistan
UkrainianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUkraine=Ukrainian, Ukraine
UpperxxSPxxSorbianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGermany=Upper Sorbian, Germany
UrduxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIslamicxxSPxxRepublicxxSPxxofxxSPxxPakistan=Urdu, Islamic Republic of Pakistan
UzbekxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUzbekistan=Uzbek (Cyrillic), Uzbekistan
UzbekxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUzbekistan=Uzbek (Latin), Uzbekistan
VietnamesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxVietnam=Vietnamese, Vietnam
WelshxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxKingdom=Welsh, United Kingdom
WolofxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSenegal=Wolof, Senegal
YakutxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Yakut, Russia
YorubaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNigeria=Yoruba, Nigeria
isiXhosaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=isiXhosa, South Africa
isiZuluxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=isiZulu, South Africa

Script stderr:


Preparing to Install
Preparing to Install
Creating directory C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5
...
Creating directory C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\symbols
Unpacking files
Unpacking C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\server_3rd_party_licenses.txt
...
Unpacking C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\symbols\pg_ctl.pdb
[17:04:36] Running the post-installation/upgrade actions:
[17:04:36] Write the base directory to the ini file...
[17:04:36] Write the version number to the ini file...
Initialising the database cluster (this may take a few minutes)...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" 5432 "English, Australia" 0
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 WScript.Shell Initialized...
Scripting.FileSystemObject initialized...

Called CreateDirectory(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data)...
Called CreateDirectory(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5)...
WScript.Network initialized...
strParentOfDataDirC:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5
logged in useruser-PC\user
Called AclCheck(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data)
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Executing icacls to ensure the user-PC\user account can read the path C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data
    Executing batch file 'radF52B7.bat'...
    processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can write to the data directory (using icacls) to  user-PC\user:
    Executing batch file 'radF52B7.bat'...
    processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

    Executing batch file 'radF52B7.bat'...
    The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "user".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/base/1 ... ok
initializing pg_authid ... ok
setting password ... ok
initializing dependencies ... ok
creating system views ... ok
loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
creating collations ... not supported on this platform
creating conversions ... ok
creating dictionaries ... ok
setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
creating information schema ... ok
loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
vacuuming database template1 ... ok
copying template1 to template0 ... ok
copying template1 to postgres ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_ctl" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" -l logfile start


Reading:    C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\postgresql.conf exists...
Writing:    C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\postgresql.conf exists...
Called AclCheck(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data)
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Executing icacls to ensure the NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService account can read the path C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data
    Executing batch file 'radF52B7.bat'...
    processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Granting service account access to the data directory (using icacls) to NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService:
    Executing batch file 'radF52B7.bat'...
    processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data
processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\base
processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\global
processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\pg_clog
processed file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\pg_commit_ts
...
Successfully processed 884 files; Failed processing 0 files

initcluster.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Configuring database server startup...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\installer\server\startupcfg.vbs" 9.5 "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "****" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" "postgresql-x64-9.5"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 startupcfg.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Creating menu shortcuts...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\installer\server\createshortcuts.vbs" 9.5 "postgres" 5432 "PostgreSQL 9.5" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" "postgresql-x64-9.5"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Start FixupFile(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\scripts\serverctl.vbs)...
   Opening file for reading...
   Closing file (reading)...
   Replacing placeholders...
   Opening file for writing...
   Closing file...
  End FixupFile()...
Start FixupFile(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\scripts\runpsql.bat)...
   Opening file for reading...
   Closing file (reading)...
   Replacing placeholders...
   Opening file for writing...
   Closing file...
  End FixupFile()...
createshortcuts.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Starting the database server...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\installer\server\startserver.vbs" postgresql-x64-9.5
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Starting postgresql-x64-9.5
Service postgresql-x64-9.5 started successfully
startserver.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


[17:05:32] Installing the adminpack module in the postgres database...
Executing C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe -c "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack" -d postgres
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 CREATE EXTENSION

Script stderr:


[17:05:34] Write the data directory to the ini file...
[17:05:34] Write the port number, service ID, locale and superuser to the ini file...
[17:05:34] Write ServiceID(postgresql-x64-9.5) to registry/ini...
[17:05:34] Write Superuser to ini file and windows registry...
[17:05:34] Write Service Account to ini file and windows registry...
[17:05:34] Write the server description to the ini file...
[17:05:34] Write the server branding to the ini file...
[17:05:34] Write the 'whether stack-builder is disabled or not' to the ini file...
[17:05:35] Finished running post-installation/upgrade tasks.
[17:05:35] Delete the temporary scripts directory...
Creating Uninstaller
Creating uninstaller 25%
Creating uninstaller 50%
Creating uninstaller 75%
Creating uninstaller 100%
Installation completed
Log finished 11/08/2017 at 17:05:47
```

From the above logs, here is the important ones which reflect the issue:

```
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" 5432 "English, Australia" 0
Script exit code: 0
.
.
.
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".
```

When I installed `PostgreSQL 8.4.8` under same conditions (in GUI mode), there were no issues with that. It got installed with locale `English, Australia`.

Any idea, what can be the reason behind this?

**Update:**

When I selected `Default Locale` in GUI mode (PostgreSQL 9.5), then only it got installed with `English, Australia` locale. Output of command `Show lc_collate` was `English_Australia.1252`.

Same issue exists in `postgresql-9.5.9-1-windows-x64.exe`

Comment: You should mention which installer you used.

Comment: It is "postgresql-9.5.2-1-windows-x64". I have updated the post as well.

Comment: Hm, is that the installer from EnterpriseDB?

Comment: Yes, the installer is from EnterpriseDB.